# How to do row validation in apex controller

Tags: apex, visualforce

I want to do row validation to check if date field is blank or not.How to do. Below is my code.

I am using a wrapper class in which i have `Date__c` object which has a field as `start__c`.

How to check by row index. `ident` in wrapper class creates the row number. How to use it in `addrows()` method to validate.

Apex Class -

```
public class Datecontroller
{


 public Date__c datev { get; set; }
 public List<AccountWrapper> wrappers {get; set;}
 public static Integer toDelIdent {get; set;}
 public static Integer addCount {get; set;}
 public string s{get;  set;}
 //public List<Date__c> dater {get;set;}
 List<Date__c> dater = new List<Date__c>();


  public List<AccountWrapper> attendeeList1 {
        get {if (attendeeList1 == null)
            attendeeList1 = new List<AccountWrapper>();
             return attendeeList1;
            }
        set;
    }


     public List<ID> selectedCategories {
        get {
            if (selectedCategories == null) {
                selectedCategories = new List<ID>();
            }
            return selectedCategories ;
        }
        set;
    }

 private Integer nextIdent=0;

     public Datecontroller(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {


    }


 public Datecontroller()
 {
  datev =  new Date__c ();
  wrappers=new List<AccountWrapper>();
  for (Integer idx=0; idx<1; idx++)
  {
   wrappers.add(new AccountWrapper(nextIdent++));
  }
 }


    public List<SelectOption> getProducts() {
       List<SelectOption> products = new List<SelectOption>();
       for(Product2 p : [SELECT Id,Name  from Product2])
           products.add(new SelectOption(p.Id, p.Name));
       return products ;
    }


 public void delWrapper()
 {
  Integer toDelPos=-1;
  for (Integer idx=0; idx<wrappers.size(); idx++)
  {
   if (wrappers[idx].ident==toDelIdent)
   {
    toDelPos=idx;
   }
  }

  if (-1!=toDelPos)
  {
   wrappers.remove(toDelPos);
  }
 }

 public void addRows()
 {
  /*for (Integer idx=0; idx<addCount; idx++)
  {
   wrappers.add(new AccountWrapper(nextIdent++));
  } */

Integer countIndex = 0;
Set<Integer> indexSet = new Set<Integer>();
for (AccountWrapper wrapper: wrappers){
         if(wrapper.acc.StartDate__c< date.valueof(date.today())){
           indexSet .add(countIndex );
         }
         countIndex ++;

  for(Integer count : indexSet ){
        wrappers[count].startdateErrorMessage ='An error occurred';
  }      


        wrappers.add(new AccountWrapper(nextIdent++));



 }
 }

 public PageReference save()
 {

  system.debug('@@@@@@@' + selectedCategories);



  List<Date__c> accs=new List<Date__c>();

for(Id catId: selectedCategories) {
  for(AccountWrapper wrapper: wrappers) {
    Date__c temp = wrapper.acc.clone(false, true, false, false);
    temp.Site__c = catId;
    temp.Advertiser__c = datev.Advertiser__c;
    temp.SalesRep__c= datev.SalesRep__c;
    accs.add(temp);
  }
}
insert accs;

 // return new PageReference('/' + Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('Date__c ').getDescribe().getKeyPrefix() + '/o');
 return null;
 }

 public class AccountWrapper
 {
  public Date__c acc {get; private set;}
  public Integer ident {get; private set;}
  public string startdateErrorMessage  {get; private set;}
  public AccountWrapper(Integer inIdent)
  {
   ident=inIdent;
   acc=new Date__c(Name='Bulk Acc ' + ident);
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure in which method you want to check but you can easily validate this using the loop

```
 for(AccountWrapper wrapper: wrappers) 
     if(wrapper.acc.start__c == null)
        system.debug('----Start is blank in this record---'+wrapper.acc);
```

You need to add error like this

```
Integer countIndex = 0;
Set<Integer> indexSet = new Set<Integer>();
for (AccountWrapper wrapper: wrappers){
         if(wrapper.acc.StartDate__c< date.valueof(date.today())){
           indexSet .add(countIndex );
         }
         countIndex ++;
  for(Integer count : indexSet)
        wrappers[count].startdateErrorMessage ='An error occurred';
```

Comment: I want to check in addRows() method..whenever it is called from vf page..it will validate.. if date is not null then it will add another row else it will throw error ..

Comment: @learningmode then you can add this for loop in starting of your method and instead of debug you can throw a exception.

Comment: I modified the code above.. I am getting an error ..Cannot modify a collection while it is being iterated.
Error is in expression '{!addRows}' in component <apex:commandButton> in page datepage: Class.Datecontroller.addRows: line 84, column 1....

Comment: This error is coming when i am clicking add row for 2nd time..for first time i am getting the custom error.. for for 2nd time it is throwing this error

Comment: @learningmode this error is coming because of this line `wrapper.startdateErrorMessage ='An error occurred';` you can store the index position ins set and then iterate over that set to add error. check my updated answer.

Comment: I am getting an error...: Loop must iterate over a collection type: Integer at line 91 column 23 
for(Integer count : countIndex )

Comment: @learningmode check my updated answer. use indexSet in loop

Comment: I am getting an error again...Cannot modify a collection while it is being iterated.
Error is in expression '{!addRows}' in component <apex:commandButton> in page datepage: Class.Datecontroller.addRows: line 86, column 1

Comment: I have updated my code which i am using now..

Comment: I think i got the issue. i need to move   wrappers.add(new AccountWrapper(nextIdent++));
 line out of the for loop..